# read csv file line by line and output the fifth column to use for matching in c

Tags: c, string, csv, line

I am new in C, and I'm trying to find a way to read `csv` file and output the fifth text in the line until eof

My data looks like this:

> 05/02/2012
>   00:00:01.548,XOLT,1ZE86V280394811433,trackthepack,23.22.11.82,en_US,
>   05/02/2012
>   00:00:01.605,XOLT,1ZVzVrZVhOaGNtUnZi,hadees,50.16.47.103,en_US,VE
>   05/02/2012
>   00:00:01.647,XOLT,1ZbWhoY21GMGFHRnVY,hadees,50.19.203.230,en_US,VE
>   05/02/2012
>   00:00:02.275,XOLT,1Z4217060300279193,trackthepack,107.21.159.246,en_US,
>   05/02/2012
>   00:00:02.599,XOLT,1Z9X98040398954479,Cascademfg,66.117.15.81,en_US,NF
>   05/02/2012
>   00:00:02.639,XOLT,1Z3X252W0363295735,trackthepack,107.22.101.79,en_US,

I would need to read this file and store the value of the fifth text (e.g. 23.22.11.82) and use it further processing of a match.

In java, I use the following code to split out the csv line

```
String delims = "[,]"; 

while ((s1 = in.readLine()) != null && s1.length() != 0){

            String[] tokens = s1.split(delims);
```

Is there a similar way in C? My code works faster if I run it in C, that is the reason.

I was able to try some c code and I was able to read the file (3 records) but it seems that it is not seeing the end of the line and I am hitting a segmentation error.
I am using fgets and strtok

THe input file is a variable length file delimiter by comma (,) and I want to get the fifth token in each line and then use it as a lookup key

here is the code :

```
    #include "GeoIP.h"
#include "GeoIPCity.h"


static const char * _mk_NA( const char * p ){
 return p ? p : "N/A";
}

int 
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  FILE           *f;
  FILE           *out_f;
  GeoIP          *gi;
  GeoIPRecord    *gir;
  int             generate = 0;
  char            iphost[50];
  char            *nextWordPtr = NULL;
  int             wordCount =0;
  char            *rechost;
  char            recbuffer[1000];
  char delims[]=",";
  const char     *time_zone = NULL;
  char          **ret;
  if (argc == 2)
    if (!strcmp(argv[1], "gen"))
      generate = 1;

  gi = GeoIP_open("../data/GeoIPCity.dat", GEOIP_MEMORY_CACHE);

  if (gi == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error opening database\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  f = fopen("city_test.txt", "r");

  if (f == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error opening city_test.txt\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  out_f = fopen("out_city_lookup_test.txt", "w");

  if (out_f == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error opening out_city_lookup_test.txt\n");
    exit(1);
  }

//** Read the file line by line and get the ip address to use to lookup GeoIP **//
//*     while (!feof(f)) {
   while (fgets(recbuffer,1001,f) != NULL {
         nextWordPtr = strtok (recbuffer,delims); 
         while (nextWordPtr != NULL & wordCount < 5) {
           printf("word%d %s\n",wordCount,nextWordPtr);
           if (wordCount == 4 ) {
               printf("nextWordPtr %s\n",nextWordPtr);
               strcpy(iphost, nextWordPtr);
               printf("iphost %s\n",iphost);
           }    
           wordCount++;
           nextWordPtr = strtok(NULL,delims);
         }
    gir = GeoIP_record_by_name(gi, (const char *) iphost);

    if (gir != NULL) {
      ret = GeoIP_range_by_ip(gi, (const char *) iphost);
      time_zone = GeoIP_time_zone_by_country_and_region(gir->country_code, gir->region);
      printf("%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%f\t%f\t%d\t%d\t%s\t%s\t%s\n", iphost,
         _mk_NA(gir->country_code),
         _mk_NA(gir->region),
         _mk_NA(GeoIP_region_name_by_code(gir->country_code, gir->region)),
         _mk_NA(gir->city),
         _mk_NA(gir->postal_code),
         gir->latitude,
         gir->longitude,
         gir->metro_code,
         gir->area_code,
         _mk_NA(time_zone),
         ret[0],
         ret[1]);
      fprintf(out_f,"%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%f\t%f\t%d\t%d\t%s\t%s\t%s\n", iphost,
         _mk_NA(gir->country_code),
         _mk_NA(gir->region),
         _mk_NA(GeoIP_region_name_by_code(gir->country_code, gir->region)),
         _mk_NA(gir->city),
         _mk_NA(gir->postal_code),
         gir->latitude,
         gir->longitude,
         gir->metro_code,
         gir->area_code,
         _mk_NA(time_zone),
         ret[0],
         ret[1]);
      GeoIP_range_by_ip_delete(ret);
      GeoIPRecord_delete(gir);
    }
  }
  GeoIP_delete(gi);

  fclose(out_f);

  return 0;
```

Comment: Yes there is, use [`strtok`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/).

Comment: Are you creating this CSV file yourself?  The CSV standard is much more complex than splitting on commas (for example, you can have a string with a comma in it by putting the string in quotes).  You should probably use http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/, which is optimized to handle CSVs efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, not as elegant but you can use [strtok](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/functions/strtok.html) to get the job done.

Comment: i encountered a segmentation error.. was wondering what i did wrong.. with the code below

Answer (score 0):

For what you want, a better approach is a [lexer](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/). If your end goal is complex, you might want a [parser](http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/index.html#Top) as well.

I've got an example lexer and parser [here](https://github.com/srathbun/example-parser). It is more complex than what you need though. If you want something simple, [strtok](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok) will do the job, but you will have several nasty surprises to watch out for. It will also be difficult to use outside the simple case you have presented here.

Comment: @ M.M i i am consuming the file from an applicationt that creates the data with the delimiter as a comma (,) . In this set of data, the comman is unique as a delimiter

Comment: i used the following code and i encountered a segmentation fault error

Comment: @Stephen.. code is attached above.. hope you can help me .. the code runs after reading the three records but seems it does not recognize end of record or end of file..

Comment: @EB, you've built a poor man's lexer. This thing is rife with bug potential, and as you've found, actually has some bugs. I suggest you read the lexer manual I linked and rebuild it. If you can't or won't, the gnu debugger will help you find where your code is not working as expected.

Comment: @Stephen.. i am not sure where to start.. the code of parsing is the one that causing my issue and you are saying that it is not a good template to start with.. just verifying.. thanks for the feedback but i have not used a gnu debugger being new in c .. so i will have to research that to even use it